# Apollo Client returns old data in mutation update function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a problem with updating cache data. I have a query called `GetMe` which gets all information about currently logged user like `id`, `displayName`, `avatar` etc.
Now I am updating user's profile with `UpdateProfileMutation` and return the same fragment with the same fields as query above. I see in database that update succeeded. Regarding the documentation, cache should be updated automatically (based on `id` and `__typename` fields) and component should rerender but it does not happen. I also tried to manually update the cache like below by `writeQuery`, but it does not work. Second argument of `update` function should be the response from server, but it is old cached data.

GetMe:

```
  const { data, error } = useGetMeQuery()
```

UpdateProfile

```
  const [update, { loading, error }] = useUpdateProfileMutation({
    variables: {
      input: {
        displayName,
        gender,
        avatar
      }
    }
  })

  const updateProfile = useCallback(async () => {
    await update({
      update: (cache, result) => {
        const data: GetMeQuery | null = cache.readQuery({
          query: GetMeDocument
        })
        const updatedProfile = result.data?.updateProfile // it should be the newest data but it is old one

        console.log(result)
        console.log(data)

        cache.writeQuery({
          query: GetMeDocument,
          data: {
            ...data,
            me: {
              ...data?.me,
              ...updatedProfile
            }
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }, [])
```

GetMe query

```
# import UserFragment from "../fragments/UserFragment.graphql"

query GetMe {
  me {
    ...UserFragment
  }
}
```

UpdateProfile mutation

```
# import UserFragment from "../fragments/UserFragment.graphql"

mutation UpdateProfile($input: ProfileInput!) {
  updateProfile(input: $input) {
    ...UserFragment
  }
}
```

UserFragment

```
fragment UserFragment on User {
  _id
  email
  gender
  displayName
  avatar
}
```

ApolloConfig

```
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: from([signRequestsLink, updateTokensLink, errorLink, splitLink])
})
```

[image]

Comment: mutation defs? network response? if bad, nothing can help - check mutation in playground (using variables, of course) before coding

Comment: @xadm as I said, return values from mutation is OK. There is something with Apollo Client (maybe cache policy?) wrong here

Comment: unknown query/mutation, unknown solution

Comment: @xadm I edited my post, added query and mutation :)

Comment: DB update result and return response can be different - network response is ok? `console.log(data, updatedProfile)` ? data structures are equal, you can just use new data `cache.writeQuery({
          query: GetMeDocument,
          data: {me: updatedProfile}})` ? - adjust details from logged structures

Comment: @xadm I inserted console logs (I edited my post). There are equal and they should not be. Of course if I restart my app I see updated data so response is OK (I also checked that)

Comment: I don't care about restart ... mutation network response is OK/different from logged? mutation tested in playground? client config?

Comment: @xadm Yes, mutation network response is different and its OK. Moreover in my case, I think I don't need to modify the cache because I have an `_id` in response and apollo should do it automatically. But it does not. Config included in post.

Comment: does it work without using fragments? insert `debugger` and explore cache internals/store entries ... what keys do you see? 'me' query entry is a ref to User:id ?